# Fourier Series with dc offset

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I have to obtain Fourier Series of 
$$ F(x)=x(2\pi-x)  $$ for $$ 0 < x < 2\pi  $$ $$ f(x) = f(x+2\pi)$$
I am very confused what to do about the last condition:  $$ f(x) = f(x+2\pi) $$ 
my calculated $a(0)$ is $-\frac{2}{3}\pi^2$
and my a(n) term is $ \frac{-2\left(\pi ^2n^2-2\right)\sin \left(\pi n\right)-4\pi n\cos \left(\pi n\right)}{\pi n^3} $
can someone confirm if these are correct?

Comment: If $n$ is an integer, then $\sin(n\pi)=1$. Similarly you can simplify $\cos(\pi n)$. I did not check if the integration was correct.